# React.js Update state inside loop with delay

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React and am trying to build a drum machine. I am completely stuck though.

I am trying to loops through an array of cells and update a boolean to true but I am trying to have a two second delay between each state update. When I click the button it updates the entire array after a 2 second delay.

I've read a bit about how to use set time out with loops but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas's???

```
import React from 'react'

class Row extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    this.delay = this.delay.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cells: this.props.cell
    }
  }

  tick(){
      this.state.cells.map((cell) => {
        this.delay(cell)
      })
  }

  delay(cell){
    setInterval(() => {
      cell.playing = true
    },2000)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>hello</div>
        <button onClick={this.tick}>Click </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Row;
```

this is the Row component. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you must use setState to set the state, and your access to the state no longer exists in the context of the timer callback.   Also you are creating separate delayed interval for each cell.  it would be better to move setting the state to a single delay function.

This is un-untested, but should point you to the right direction.  Note the array slice makes a copy of the modified array then we use setState to update the cells.

```
import React from 'react'

class Row extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    this.delay = this.delay.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cells: this.props.cell
    }
  }

  tick(){
      this.delay(this.state.cells);
  }

  delay(cells){
    var that = this;
    setInterval(() => {
       var newCellState = cells.map((cell) => { 
          cell.playing = true
        }); 
       that.setState({cells: newCellSate});
    },2000)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>hello</div>
        <button onClick={this.tick}>Click </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Row;
```